# Proving the Validity of a Given Inequality Involving Ratios of $p$ and $q$

Tags: inequality

Consider the following inequality:

$$\left(\frac{p}{1-q}\right)^p \geq \left(\frac{q}{1-p}\right)^{1-p}$$

where $0<p<1$ and $0<q<1$. I am trying to show that the following inequality holds true for all values of $p$ and $q$ that meet the conditions.
I appreciate any help.

My approach is to investigate different relationships between p
and q
. For example, (1) $q<p<0.5$
. In this case, we can get rid of the exponents by replacing the right side of the inequality with $(q/(1−p))^p$
and show the left side is still bigger. But this approach does not always work. For example when (2) $p>0.5>q$
.

Comment: Show me your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg My approach is to investigate different relationships between $p$ and $q$. For example, (1) $q < p < 0.5$. In this case, we can get rid of the exponents by replacing the right side of the inequality with $(q/(1-p))^p$ and show the left side is still bigger. But this approach does not always work. For example when (2) $p > 0.5 > q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}\right)^p\geq\frac{q}{1-p},$$ which is true by Bernoulli:
$$\left(\frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}\right)^p=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{(1-p)(1-q)}{pq}-1\right)^p}\geq\frac{1}{1+p\left(\frac{(1-p)(1-q)}{pq}-1\right)}=\frac{q}{1-p}.$$

Comment: Is the condition $p+q < 1$ needed at all?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Very smart use of Bernoulli inequality. Thank you!